# Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I have a code like this and I get an error:-

```
<FieldArray
        name="amenities"
        render={arrayHelpers => (
          <div>
            {values.amenitieslist && values.amenitieslist.length > 0 ? (
              values.amenitieslist.map((amenity, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  <Field name={`amenitieslist.${index}.name`} />
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} // remove a friend from the list
                  >
                    -
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({ id: "", name: "" })}>
                {/* show this when user has removed all friends from the list */}
                Add a friend
              </button>
            )}
            <div>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      />
```

If I do this I get an error Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact.

If I try moving to another method like this:-

```
const displayAmenities = (values, arrayHelper)=>{
}
```

I get an error that 'values' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How do I work around this ??. I am not supposed to change any rules around lambda expressions. Is there a legitimate way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

> 'values' implicitly has an 'any' type

This error simply means that TypeScript can't figure out the type of the parameter `values` on its own. The easiest fix is to just specify the type like this:

```js
const displayAmenities = (values: SomeType[], arrayHelper: SomeOtherType)=>{
    // ...
}
```

Since I don't know the types of those variables either, I can't tell you exactly what to use. Just replace `SomeType` and `SomeOtherType` with the types from your project.

Comment: since arrayHelper is from fomik callback it would be `import { ArrayHelpers } from 'formik';`  and `arrayHelpers: ArrayHelpers`

Comment: @lukasgeiter - That makes sense. How do I call this function from render ?

Comment: @SaiBand I haven't seen your full code but I would say something like `displayAmenities(values, arrayHelper)`? If you need more help please update your question with the full code of your component. (at least the relevant parts)

Comment: @lukasgeiter - I have pasted my code in the top section of the question. My question is if I have to call a method instead of a lambda expression in render, how do I do this.

Comment: @lukasgeiter - You see how I am using a lambda expression instead of a function. How do I call a function instead of that.

Comment: Well you would just pass the function/method to render: `render={displayAmenities}` . The problem with this of course is that then the function won't be called with `values` as first argument. I give you any further help because I don't know where `values` is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

To solve that issue quickly (since I am deploying something to deliver today) in my Typescript React project, I simply edited the file called tslint.json, and included one new rule: "jsx-no-lambda": false.

The tslint.json file excerpt is here:

```
  ...
  "rules": {
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    ...
  }
  ...
```

I hope it helps you guys, I took some time to get it.